# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code. The error in Chrome is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".

I'm trying to get data from a form and display it in a div on the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getfromForm()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('name_txtbox').val();
    var number = document.getElementById('phone_txtbox').val();
    var email = document.getElementById('email_txtbox').val();
    var message = document.getElementById('message_txtbox').val();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(message);
    document.getElementById('name1').html(name);
    document.getElementById('phone1').html(number);
    document.getElementById('email1').html(email);
    document.getElementById('msg1').html(message);
};
​</script>
```

[http://i.imgur.com/Us7RlOv.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGVz5.jpg)

Comment: `.val()` is jQuery, not native.. also the syntax is `getElementById` not `getElementbyid`

Comment: @urbz: That doesn't fit the symptom, however.

Comment: here is my <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Assets/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: You have to use this method var name = document.getElementById('name_txtbox')
console.log(name.value)

Comment: I think urbz is probably correct on this one, but w/o seeing the full console error it will be hard to tell.  Also, please note you don't need semicolons following a named function declaration.

Comment: @urbz i changed it, error still there

Comment: Can you setup a JsFiddle for us to see the whole code? html,css,js

Comment: At least tell on which line the error is. Also, if you click on the error message in the console it'll show you what the unexpected token is.

Comment: If you've fixed those issues in your code, I'd suggest editing your question to fix them in your snippet as well. As more users visit this question, it will most likely be the first thing they see, and as such you'll get misleading answers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pyeqduzp/

Comment: That JSFiddle does throw errors, but not the one you describe in the question. Please edit the JSFiddle so that it matches the question.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pyeqduzp/2/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Us7RlOv.jpg

Comment: Ok, apparently you can't make a fiddle that would replicate the error. In your  own code, click on the "Contact.html:35" text on the right side of the error message. The console will then show the line and character that is the invalid character.

Comment: @JJJ line 35 is the final line "}" in said function from the original post

Comment: @JJJ http://i.imgur.com/DBblmnt.jpg I was wrong it is the next line

Comment: Well there's obviously an invalid character just before the closing </script> tag. It's probably a non-breaking space or something like that. Just completely delete that line (and the previous line too, just in case) and rewrite it.

Comment: @JJJ: Yup, and it's even in the question, because Keanan was a good boy and copy-and-pasted. I didn't catch it earlier because I only copied the *code*, not the `script` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Invalid/unexpected tokens

<s>The code **in the question** has no invalid/unexpected tokens.</s> *(Edit: Yes it does, I just didn't copy enough of it.)* I can think of two reasons you might be getting that error:

1. <s>If you have exactly what's in the question (with the script tags) in a `.js` file you're loading like this:</s>

   ```
   <script src="filename.js"></script>
   ```

   ...then that's the problem: You don't put `script` tags in JavaScript files. Remove them from the `.js` file. *(Edit: But you've said the error points to the `};` at the end of the function, so that's not it.)*
2. You have an invisible character in the code. Specifically, it's just prior to the `</script>` on the line *after* the line the browser is complaining about, a `U+200B` character ([zero-width space](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=200b); these seem to show up a fair bit; JSBin used to insert them in odd places, for instance). Delete that entire line, then retype the `</script>`.

#### Other issues

The code does have several problems other than invalid/unexpected tokens:

- It tries to call `undefined` as a function (because of the capitalization issue urbz mentioned in the second part of his/her comment): It should be `getElementById`, not `getElementByid`.
- If you fix that, it tries to use a jQuery function on a DOM element, but jQuery functions are only available on jQuery objects, not DOM elements.
- If you fix that, later on it tries to use another jQuery function (`html`) on a DOM element.
- It has an unnecessary (but harmless) `;` after the function declaration.

Using jQuery, that code would look like this:

```
function getfromForm()
{
    var name = $('#name_txtbox').val()
    var number = $('#phone_txtbox').val();
    var email = $('#email_txtbox').val();
    var message = $('#message_txtbox').val();
    console.log(name);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(message);
    $('#name1').html(name);
    $('#phone1').html(number);
    $('#email1').html(email);
    $('#msg1').html(message);
}
```

**Not** using jQuery, just using the DOM API directly, it would be:

```
function getfromForm()
{
    var name = document.getElementById('#name_txtbox').value
    var number = document.getElementById('phone_txtbox').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email_txtbox').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message_txtbox').value;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(number);
    console.log(email);
    console.log(message);
    document.getElementById('name1').innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById('phone1').innerHTML = number;
    document.getElementById('email1').innerHTML = email;
    document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = message;
}
```

More to explore:

- [Mozilla Developer's Network's JavaScript pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript)
- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [DOM API](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/)

Comment: That seems to have fixed the error, its not in a seperate .js file for clarity

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out when you said line 35 was pointing to the `}` line. :-) (You may not see the edits to the answer, I suggest hitting refresh.)

Comment: Yeah thanks so much, I still have a few other errors but those I can fix, I just couldnt figure out what the hell that error was for, I appreciate it

Comment: @KeananTydeFlowerday: Frankly, I've seen it before and should have twigged earlier. :-) Glad to help.